# Getting error while debugging my windows form

Tags: c#, database, forms

According to my program the first row of my table should be displayed in their respective text boxes .
But I am getting an error :Invalid Object name 'tbl_employees'. Which is caught by my catch block.I have to a class form1 and a class databaseconnections.Also when i click OK on the error message the form loads but the data is not displayed in the textboxes.

```
class DatabaseConnection
{
    private string sql_string;
    private string strCon;
    SqlDataAdapter da_1;

    public string Sql 
    {
        set { sql_string = value; }
    }

    public string Connection_string
    {
        set { strCon = value; }
    }

    public DataSet Getconnection
    {
        get { return MyDataSet(); }
    }

    public DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        con.Open();

       SqlDataAdapter da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);

        DataSet dat_set = new DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();

        return dat_set;
    }

}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DatabaseConnection objConnect;
    string conString;

    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dRow;

    int MaxRows;
    int inc = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.Employees1ConnectionString;

            objConnect.Connection_string = conString;
            objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

            ds = objConnect.Getconnection;
            MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            NavigateRecords();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message,"Error");
        }   
    }

    private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
        txtFirstname.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        txtSurname.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        txtJobtitle.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txtDepartment.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your SQL query, might be pointing to wrong table.

Comment: And what is the name of the table you are trying to access?

Comment: In the settings section under the Value column I have written SELECT*FROM tbl_employees which is the name of the table.

Comment: Ok i got the error...I misspelled the name of the table :/